# using Marshal.FreeHGlobal after Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, dllexport

I'm writing a DLL in C# that is called from Delphi using `dllexport`.

The basics is very simple and works, but I wanted to expose a function that returns fills a string with specific message (not returning a string). The way I'm doing it is that the Delphi sends the function a pointer of type wide string (`LPWSTR`) and I fill  it. This works well. However, when I do it, I need to free the memory and this is where I'm not sure I did the right thing.
The DLL is build in one class that implement `IDisposable`. This is because I need to free the memory after the function executes.

Here is the class and this one function.

In order to release the memory I allocate, I declare a global static `intPtr`, which I release as dispose. Here is the code.

Would be happy to get any feedback

```
namespace simpleDLL
{
    public class Test : IDisposable
    {
        public delegate int prog(int i);

        static IntPtr s_copy;
        bool disposed = false;
        [DllExport("getString", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static int getString(out IntPtr s, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string str)
        {

            s_copy = (IntPtr)Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(str);
            s = s_copy;
            return str.Length;
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
        }
        // Protected implementation of Dispose pattern.
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposed)
                return;

            if (disposing)
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(s_copy);
                // Free any other managed objects here.
                //
            }

            // Free any unmanaged objects here.
            //
            disposed = true;
        }
        ~Test()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: To post code: in a text editor, shift right four spaces, then copy and paste into your post.  Best to avoid tabs.

Comment: Allocate by caller, pass to function, release by caller. Simple rule of thumb.

Comment: @Jeff: or just copy and paste the text as-is, select it and press the `{}` toolbar button in the question/answer editor.

Comment: The overall ideas seems sound. Note, however, that each call to `getString` will overwrite the previous value of `s_copy`, potentially causing a leak.